# Retrieving the most recent entry per user

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with the following structure and data:

```
id | user_id | created_at
-------------------------
 1 |       7 |    0091942
 2 |       3 |    0000014
 3 |       6 |    0000890
 4 |       6 |    0029249
 5 |       7 |    0000049
 6 |       3 |    0005440
 7 |       9 |    0010108
```

What query would I use to get the following results (explanation to follow):

```
id | user_id | created_at
-------------------------
 1 |       7 |    0091942
 6 |       3 |    0005440
 4 |       6 |    0029249
 7 |       9 |    0010108
```

As you can see:

- Only one row per `user_id` is returned.
- The row with the highest `created_at` is the one returned.

Is there a way to accomplish this **without** using subqueries?  Is there a name in relational algebra parlance that this procedure goes by?

Comment: In SQL Server you can use the ranking function `row_number()`, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in MySql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: Please feel free to post the subquery-based solution if you'd like so I can flag it correct.

Comment: you should change created_at column into datetime so you can fetch teh latest date i think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query is known as a [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which (in MySQL, at least) can be implemented with a subquery.  For example:

```
SELECT my_table.* FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   user_id, MAX(created_at) created_at
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY user_id
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4ffa/1/0).

Comment: +1 for showing a NATURAL JOIN, for which I've never seen a use (preferring explicit INNER joins).

Comment: Sorry for the archaeological excursion, but "can only be implemented"?? That wasn't true then, and it ain't true now!

Comment: Old school: "LEFT JOIN...WHERE IS NULL"

Comment: @eggyal as per the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 2):

You can just get the max and group by the user_id:

```
select id,user_id,max(created_at)
from supportContacts
group by user_id
order by id;
```

Here is what it outputs:

```
ID  USER_ID MAX(CREATED_AT)
1   7   91942
2   3   5440
3   6   29249
7   9   10108
```

See the working [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1047d1/5)

Note that the example on the fiddle uses the created_at field as int, just use your format it should make no difference.

***EDIT: I will leave this answer as a referece but note that his query will produce undesired results as Gordon stated, please do not use this in production.***

Comment: Interesting, SQL Server wouldn't let you do that since `id` is not part of the `group by` and not aggregated either.

Comment: yeah, postgreSQL won't either, luckily mysql does.

Comment: @isJustMe . . . MySQL documentation is explicitly clear that the results are not defined ("The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.").  You can read the documentation here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff excelent catch, I would have never noted that... I left an edit warning that it should not be used, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: More than just "*might produce undesired results*", the example actually *does* produce undesired results.  Note that the `ID` values returned for `USER_ID` 3 and 6 are 2 and 3 respectively, whereas they should be 6 and 4.  (Also be aware that if you delete this answer, you'll be rewarded with a shiny [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) badge).

Comment: @eggyal edited the "might" for a "will", however I think is useful to leave the answer as it might help other users to avoid this this type of issues.