# Performing a Groupwise Maximum in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

What's the best way to perform a [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) using Laravel's Eloquent ORM such that it returns instances of models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034960/retrieving-the-most-recent-entry-per-user), I was able to create the following:

```
    $query = MyModel
        ::from(DB::raw(
            'my_models NATURAL JOIN (
                SELECT   user_id, MAX(created_at) created_at
                FROM     my_models
                GROUP BY user_id
            ) t'
        ))
    ;
```

Comment: 39 seconds from question to self-answer! Man, that's fast!!

Comment: I'm putting it to the community to come up with a better solution than my own.  Otherwise, this answer serves to help others who faced the same problem as me.  Not so bad when you think about it.